# How to disable intrinsics usage for the JIT compiler?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I am doing some performance tests on the `JVM`, and I would like to measure the impact of intrinsics usage.

I would like to disable the `JIT` use of intrinsics for some methods without going into the interpreted mode. Is there a way to do that ? Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:DisableIntrinsic=_<method_name>[,...]
```

For example

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:DisableIntrinsic=_equals,_hashCode
```

As @apangin noticed, you may use `-XX:+PrintIntrinsics` first to see which methods are actually intrinsified in your test and disable them.

Comment: It may be even easier to build a custom HotSpot where `Compile::make_vm_intrinsic` always returns NULL to disable all intrinsics at once.

Comment: That's probably an overkill if author just wants to measure some specific thing. But sounds cool!

Comment: Oh, I think there is a simple solution: first use `-XX:+PrintIntrinsics` to print all compiled intrinsics, then `-XX:DisableIntrinsic=` to disable them.

Comment: Added this to the answer.

Comment: BTW, I've created a [table of all JVM intrinsics](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1e9f4cab9f659982df82)

Comment: @apangin, interesting! Which JVM version is this? I don't see anything which appeared in Java 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78410/discussion-between-tagir-valeev-and-apangin).

Comment: That were JDK 7u80 intrinsics. Now [JDK 8u45 intrinsics](https://gist.github.com/apangin/7a9b7062a4bd0cd41fcc).

Comment: I have one more question how do you disable all of the intrinsic methods ?

Comment: @Bionix1441 Unfortunately there is no such switch in stock JVM. So, you have to either patch JVM or disable them one by one.

Comment: Up-to-date searchable table with all JDK intrinsics split per versions: https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_intrinsics_openjdk17.html