# Different behavior between debug and normal execution mode - WeakReference handling

Tags: java, debugging, reference, jvm

I patched the `java.lang.ref.Reference` class to call a custom native method whenever `get()` is called. The patched class is prepended to the bootstrap classpath.

When I start a sample program I see lot of print outs coming from my native method (as expected) as there are lot of `Reference`s used internally by the JDK.

The strange behavior starts in my `main` method. All I'm doing is creating a `WeakReference` to an object, deleting the strong one and calling `get()`. For whatever reason the native method I added does not seem to be called in run mode and I do not get any print outs nor other events that are happening inside the native.

If I start the program in debug mode everything works as expected, i.e. the native method is called.

If I change the `WeakReference` to a `SoftReference` it always works, also in normal run mode.

I even tried adding other code (like a `System.out.println` to the `get()`) but that also did not work. The printing somehow stops for my `WeakReference` when running in non-debug mode. In debug it always works.

Sometimes I even get a lot of events / print outs from `Finalizer`s after my main, during shut down. So it really seems like the `Reference` class somehow behaves differently.

Comment: It might be useful if you included some code samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.lang.ref.Reference.get()` is a [JVM intrinsic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function).

This means that once the method is JIT-compiled, its Java implementation is not called anymore. HotSpot compiler replaces a call to `Reference.get` with a special manually optimized sequence [hardcoded in HotSpot sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/792ccf73293a/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l6269).

At JVM startup the method is not yet JIT-compiled, i.e. its Java implementation is interpreted, and intrinsic does not work.

`SoftReference` [overrides](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e56bb18a4dff/src/share/classes/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.java#l111) the method, so `Reference.get` intrinsic does not work for it either.

You may disable this intrinsic with the following JVM flags, and your modified version will always work, even after the method is JIT-compiled:

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:DisableIntrinsic=_Reference_get
```

[Here is the list](https://gist.github.com/apangin/8bc69f06879a86163e490a61931b37e8) of other intrinsic methods in JDK.

Comment: You are the man! Wasn't aware of the hardcoded intrinsics and hence excluded JIT from my considerations as naively I thought "will be JIT compiled, but logic will remain". The flags did not work though. Neither `-XX:DisableIntrinsic=_Reference_get` nor what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370959/how-to-disable-intrinsics-usage-for-the-jit-compiler) to disable all. `-XX:CompileCommand="exclude java/lang/ref/Reference  get"` did the job though, but I think I better go with a subclass of `WeakReference` and dynamically replace all code to use that one instead. Thanks!

Comment: @HaasipSatang Ah, right: `-XX:DisableIntrinsic` disables C2 intrinsic, but the method is still intrinsified by C1.