# Why lib func in java is running faster than customized?

Tags: java

I did some investigation for Integer.bitCount recently.
I found a interesting result that Integer.bitCount is much faster than my own func, even the code is the same.

I thought is due to JIT, but I checked the document, and found the JIT is based on runtime strategy. It confused me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long sum = 0;
    long start, end;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE; i != Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        sum += bitCount(i);
        //sum += Integer.bitCount(i);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println(end - start);
}

private static int bitCount(int i) {
    i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x33333333);
    i = (i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
    i = i + (i >>> 8);
    i = i + (i >>> 16);
    return i & 0x3f;
}
```

// for bitCount result

```
68719476736
8715
```

// for Integer.bitCount result

```
68719476736
1892
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your benchmark is not accurate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) But disregarding that, one reason is because `Integer#bitCount` is marked as `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`. This means that the HotSpot JVM can replace the method body with assembly code to improve performance. From the annotation's [source code](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate.java):

> The `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation is specific to the HotSpot Virtual Machine. It indicates that an annotated method may be (but is not guaranteed to be) intrinsified by the HotSpot VM. A method is intrinsified if the HotSpot VM replaces the annotated method with hand-written assembly and/or hand-written compiler IR -- a compiler intrinsic -- to improve performance. The `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation is internal to the Java libraries and is therefore not supposed to have any relevance for application code.

Try [disabling intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370959/how-to-disable-intrinsics-usage-for-the-jit-compiler) and running your test again; you should see a significant slowdown.

Comment: [`-XX:DisableIntrinsic=_bitCount_i`](https://gist.github.com/apangin/7a9b7062a4bd0cd41fcc#file-hotspot-jvm-intrinsics)

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried that option. It did show the main reason is intrinsic. But I didn't find out that @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate annotation in source code. Only found a func list in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l581